# Isso é um tipo de "Implementação Anônima"?

Tags: java

Uma vez que não se faz instâncias de interfaces, o que o código abaixo faz com a interface [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)?

```
Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<T>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

---

- Parece que o Runtime cria uma "classe anônima" e implementa a interface nela. É isso?
- Qual nome se dá a essa situação?
- Se esse código estivesse dentro de um laço de repetição, seria criada uma nova instância para cada iteração?
- Essas instâncias teriam todas o mesmo tipo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Parece que o Runtime cria uma "classe anônima" e implementa a interface nela. É isso?

Quase. Na verdade quem a cria é o compilador. Se você fizer isso dentro de uma classe `Xpto`, poderá ver um arquivo `Xpto$1.class` surgir no conjunto de classes compiladas. Essas classes geradas pelo compilador com `$número` no nome são classes anônimas.

> - Qual nome se dá a essa situação?

Classe anônima.

> - Se esse código estivesse dentro de um laço de repetição, seria criada uma nova instância para cada iteração?

O número de instâncias criadas é exatamente o mesmo que o número de vezes que a palavra chave `new` é encontrada. Por exemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Imagina que substituíssemos a classe anônima por uma implementação chamada `Temp`:

```
class Temp implements Comparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        return 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Collections.sort(obj, new Temp());
}
```

E então, fica claro onde é que as instâncias são criadas.

> - Essas instâncias teriam todas o mesmo tipo?

Sim, pois a classe anônima é resolvida em tempo de compilação. É como se o compilador pegasse todo o corpo da classe anônima, criasse um novo arquivo de classe, copiasse e colasse esse código lá, e substituísse a instanciação da classe anônima por uma instanciação desta classe. Exatamente como fiz no código acima.

A finalidade da classe anônima é exatamente a de evitar a necessidade de se declarar uma classe completa sendo que a finalidade é apenas prover uma implementação simples de alguma interface ou classe abstrata para fazer algum trabalhinho bobo.

Uma outra coisa a se notar são os lambdas do Java 8+. Por exemplo, isso:

```
Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<T>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

É equivalente a isso:

```
Collections.sort(obj, (t1, t2) -> 0);
```

Aqui, o compilador faz deduções bem agressivas e complexas para que o conteúdo do `Comparator` tenha uma sintaxe extremamente enxuta.